# ¿Cómo concatenar 2 input text en una JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Tengo 2 input text en una JSP y quiero concatenarlos en la parte JSP. ¿Hay alguna manera posible? He intentado lo siguiente. A lo sumo puedo usar JavaScript.

```
<label for="expediente" class="textoformulario">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nº Expediente: </label>
<input type="text" name="Expediente" id="Expediente" value="<%String Expediente=request.getParameter("Expediente"); %>" size="20"/>
<label for="anyo" class="textoformulario">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/ </label>
<input type="text" name="Anyo" id="Anyo" value="<%String Anyo =request.getParameter("Anyo"); %>" size="20"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<%=multiconsultaBean.setNmExpediente(Expediente+Anyo)%>"
       name="NmExpediente" id="NmExpediente" size="4" maxlength="2" style="background-color:#cccccb" READONLY/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una muy mala práctica usar trozos de código Java en los ficheros JSP, intenta evitarlo, usando [JSP EL (JSP expression language)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/819-3669/bnahq/index.html).

Además, puedes usar el objeto implícito `param` para acceder cómodamente a los parámetros:

```
<label for="expediente" class="textoformulario">Nº Expediente: </label>
<input type="text" name="Expediente" id="Expediente" value="${param.Expediente}" size="20"/>
<label for="anyo" class="textoformulario">/ </label>
<input type="text" name="Anyo" id="Anyo" value="${param.Anyo}" size="20"/>
<input type="hidden" value="${param.Expediente}${param.Anyo}"
   name="NmExpediente" id="NmExpediente" size="4" maxlength="2" style="background-color:#cccccb"/>
```